# Docker - Getting error while trying to build image

Tags: docker, .net-core, window, console-application

I am new with docker, trying to create my first docker image/container with .net core console application in Windows 10, following the article https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-docker-for-windows-containerize-a-c-sharp-console-app/

I am getting the error message when building image:

```
COPY /bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/publish/ . COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder989987487\bin
```

The content of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0.4-runtime-nanoserver-1709 AS base  

WORKDIR /app  
COPY /bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/publish/ .  

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp1.dll"]
```

- `C:\DotNetCore\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1` is the root of my folder,
  where I palced above Dockerfile.
- `C:\DotNetCore\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\publish`
  is the folder where content is get published by `dotnet publish`
  command.

Command used to create the image:

```
docker build -t alphaimage .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, by removing the first `/` in the source directory of `COPY`:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0.4-runtime-nanoserver-1709 AS base  

WORKDIR /app  
COPY bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/publish/ /app  

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp1.dll"]
```

Comment: Still getting same error *COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder077812594\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\publish: The system cannot find the path specified.*

Comment: I think docker is not able to find the folder

Comment: you said that `netcoreapp2.1` is the folder name after `dotnet publish`, but you are trying to copy from `netcoreapp2.0`

Comment: content is published to */bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/publish/* and COPY command is showing the same * bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/publish/*

Comment: Then try to COPY in a different folder. Maybe there is a bin folder already present in ur container

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183946/discussion-between-m-idrees-and-t-prisar).

Answer (score 0):

You are publishing to a folder that has `netcoreapp2.1` in its name and the dockerfile is looking for a folder with `netcoreapp2.0` in its name.

EITHER:

Change your csproj to use `netcoreapp2.0`:

`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>`

OR

Update your COPY statement to use netcoreapp2.1

`COPY /bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/publish/ .`